# MongoDB, common part of 2 Querys

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I got document that looks like this

```
@Document(collection="myDocument")
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<Dates> dates;
}

public class Dates{
    private String key;     
    private DateTime value;
}
```

And `OtherDocument` is container for DateTime values from various sources, I can't simply make fields like `DateTime birthdate;` inside `MyDocument` because I don't know what `key` will be, they are just some dates that describe `MyDocument`. Now, I need to create search engine for those values, for example, someone want's to find all `MyDocuments` with `dates` that contains: 
`key` : "Birthdate" greater than
 
`value` : "1990-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00" 
and 
`key` : "Mather's birthday" less than 
`value`: "1975-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00"

So, `Criteria` (using `MongoTemplate` here) first may look like this

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("myDocument.dates.value")
    .exists(true)
    .gt(DateTimeUtil.valueOf("1990-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00"))  //just converting String to DateTime here      
    .and("myDocument.dates.name")
    .exists(true)
    .all("Birthday"));
```

And second one:

```
 Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("myDocument.dates.value")
     .exists(true)
     .lt(DateTimeUtil.valueOf("1975-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00"))  
     .and("myDocument.dates.name")
     .exists(true)
     .all("Mather's birthday"));
```

The problem is, I can't put those both `Criteria` in one `Query`, it will cause error. The only soultion I found till now is to make 2 separate `Query` in that case and then find common part by using
`resultA.retainAll(resultB)`

But the point is, I don't want to, this database will store **a lot** of data and those requests will be **very** frequent. I need this to work fast, and combining 2 lists in pure Java will be slow as hell with that amount of data. Any ideas how to deal with that?

edit#
here is the error thrown when I try to combine 2 `Criteria` like this in one `Query`

> caught: (java.lang.RuntimeException), msg(json can't serialize type :
>   class org.joda.time.DateTime) java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't
>   serialize type : class org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection ? How is name field mapped ?

Comment: Well the important part is pretty simple `myDocument : {
 dates : [
  { 
   name: "date1",
   value "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
  },
  { 
   name: "date2",
   value "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
  },
  { 
   name: "dateX",
   value "2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
  },
 ]
}` List of dates can have various number of elements, one Document will have 30 dates, the other one will have 3. Name values can be different too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code. `$and` the query together and use `$elemMatch` to match the dates fields on multiple condition.

Something like

```
Criteria criteria1 = Criteria.where("dates").
    elemMatch(
      Criteria.where("value").exists(true).gt(DateTimeUtil.valueOf("1990-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00"))
      .and("name").exists(true).all("Birthday")
);
Criteria criteria2 = Criteria.where("dates").
    elemMatch(
      Criteria.where("value").exists(true).lt(DateTimeUtil.valueOf("1975-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00"))
       .and("name").exists(true).all("Mather's birthday")
);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criteria1, criteria2);
```

Note: You may still have the problem with joda time conversion.